# ifconfig dirties inode on proc (Linux)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, ifconfig

I'm currently checking HD access with the following

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/block_dump
tail -f /tmp/syslog
```

and this log message pops up once in a while:

```
Aug 31 22:44:18 Frasse kernel: [ 4818.570038] ifconfig(2817): dirtied inode 4026531841 (net) on proc
```

What does it mean? Does it involve HD writes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is coming from a process named ifconfig, which is responsible for controlling your network interfaces. That inode is probably responsible for a network socket and something weird is going on with your network interface. So, no, probably not related to HD writes.

Answer (score 2):

The data in a cache is "clean" when it has been synchronized, and "dirty" when it is different.

A dirty inode has had new data written into it but it has not been written to disk.

Answer (score 2):

This discussion thread seems to discuss this issue and has a lot of details on it: [kjournald constantly accessing disk](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=369759)

One of the posts says that they had luck with enabling "noatime" on the file-system mount, but there are other good suggestions there as well.

Sean

Comment: Yeah, already did that. Now I'm down to using about 3 W on my green computer. :)

Answer (score 1):

/proc is a special virtual filesystem that looks into the kernel mechanics, and thus does not affect any disk.